# How to add "" to paths in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

Basically, I want to make it so that if I run a command, say

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/
```

it will replace that path with `"~/Library/Application Support/"`
Is this at all possible? I would also like it to apply to paths in my `.zshrc`.

Thanks

Comment: Escape space with backslash? `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/`

Comment: If you use **Tab**-Completion `zsh` will automatically quote whitespacese. Of course you have to press **Tab** before the first whitespace, otherwise `zsh` has no way of knowing that the previous and current *word* should be taken as one. Bonus: `~/Lib` **Tab** `App` **Tab** can be typed faster than `~/Library/Application Support/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around my specific issue by creating a symbolic link.
I was unable to use tab-completion/change the path manually as the issue was from [here](https://github.com/dschep/ntfy). Specifically the shell-integration.
Edit: Turns out that this issue was due to a [bug](https://github.com/dschep/ntfy/commit/34accf23c05b3bd07b013713c0776b809b2297c0) in the program.